# Does the wing to fuselage fittings of an airplane ever experience shear load?

Tags: wing, ultralight, airplane

Do wing attach fittings of semi-cantilevered plane (i.e. ultralights) ever get subjected to shear force? For example during roll, does the centrifugal force of the wings load the wing attach fittings with shear?

Comment: shear in which direction?

Comment: Span wise direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the answer is yes. The answer depends on the details of the fittings. Note that most realistic loadings are a combination of tension rsp. compression and shear. If - for example - the wing of your ultralight is held together by shear pins (note the name!) which are inserted in vertical (up-down) or horizontal (forward-backward) direction, they will transmit those centrifugal loads as shear from one wing bushing to the other.

The same goes for the transfer of lift forces inside the spar and - again, depending on the details - into the fuselage. The web of the spar is meant to carry the shear loads and those are transferred by ribs to the attachment points. Other designs use a front and rear spar which attach directly to the fuselage.

[image: B-17 front spar attachment]

The picture shows the front spar attachment of the B-17 ([source](http://legendsintheirowntime.com/LiTOT/Content/1944/B17_Av_4402_sk_spar_p137_W.png)). Granted, this is not exactly an ultralight, but the same principles apply. At positions C, D and E it uses shear pins to transfer the lift loads into the fuselage bulkhead.